# Migrating PWA to different domain?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Can we migrate a PWA to a different domain?

I tried it test wise, simply pointing the domain where the PWA was set up to a different web page.
On the browser, after some refreshing, the new page was loading instead of the PWA. But on the phone where I have the PWA installed, the PWA loads like before.

We would like to avoid that users continue to use the installed PWA, which obviously won't get any updates anymore since its origin changed. It would be ok, to have them install the PWA from its new origin manually if it's not possible to migrate it somehow automatically. But even then, they should be made aware.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I want to migrate my pwa to a subdomain without affecting any users who installed it already.

Comment: @OliverMillington no unfortunately not :(